# What do $\gamma$-radonifying operators radonify?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability

In the second volume of their [*Analysis in Banach Spaces*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-69808-3), Hytönen et al. introduce the notion of *$\gamma$-radonifying operator* more or less as follow.

> Let $(\gamma_j)_{j\in\mathbf N}$ be a sequence of independent standard gaussian random variables. Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $X$ be a Banach space. A continuous linear operator $T:H\to X$ is said to be *$\gamma$-summing* if
> $$\|T\|_{\gamma_\infty(H,X)}:=\sup_{(h_1,\dots,h_k)}\mathbf E\left\|\sum_{1\leq j\leq k}\gamma_j\,T(h_j)\right\|<+\infty,$$
> where the supremum is taken as $(h_1,\dots,h_k)$ ranges over the set of all finite orthonormal families of elements of $H$. The space $\gamma_\infty(H,X)$ of $\gamma$-summing operators from $H$ to $X$ is a vector space containing all continuous finite rank linear operators from $H$ to $X$ and on which $\|\cdot\|_{\gamma_\infty(H,X)}$ is a norm. A $\gamma$-summing operator $T:H\to X$ is said to be *$\gamma$-radonifying* if it is adherent, for the norm $\|\cdot\|_{\gamma_\infty(H,X)}$, to the space of continuous finite rank linear operators from $H$ to $X$.

They later make some brief historical comments about more general radonification questions and claim that the a continuous linear operator $T:H\to X$ is $\gamma$-radonifying if and only if the pushforward by $T$ of the standard gaussian [cylindrical measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_set_measure) on $H$ is a Radon measure on $X$ (although they wrote this in a "linear random function" point of view) and that this characterization can be found in Kuo's [*Gaussian Measures in Banach Spaces*](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0082007).

Skimming through Kuo's book, I was unable to locate the exact whereabouts of this characterization. Though I might simply have missed it or dismissed statements which would appear clearly equivalent if read through the eyes of a probabilist (which I am not).

**So my question is:** Is this characterization even true? And if it is, where can one find details about it?